# Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 Front End on React js using node js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, hyperledger-fabric

I've recently created a custom hyperledger fabric 2.2 blockchain network using javascript and want to connect it to a React.js front end using node.js API. Tried searching some examples but they are mostly on hyperledger fabric 1.4

Are there any samples/examples available for this specific case where I can get help from. Thanks!

Comment: You have node-SDK to handle your blockchain network requests. You'll have to expose APIs from your middleware/node.js server to your frontend to establish a connection. What exactly is the issue you're facing in this?

Answer (score 0):

#### fabric-samples

- [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/v2.1.1)

> The link I suggested is tagged as v2.1.1 (verified), but I confirmed that it works with fabric 2.2.

You can use `fabric-samples` to get started working with Hyperledger Fabric.
explore important Fabric features, and learn how to build applications that can interact with blockchain networks using the Fabric SDKs. To learn more about Hyperledger Fabric, visit the Fabric documentation.

---

#### fabric-sdk-node

- [doc-2.2](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.html)
- [github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)

The actual implementation example is attached under the `fabcar/javascript`, `fabcar/typescript` directory of the fabcar directory from the link. See this.

I refer more to the official documentation when developing. In the case of the actual official document, you can know about the node-sdk specification related to 2.2. Of course, for more detailed information other than the above document, analyze the fabric-sdk-node code itself and proceed with development.